# the expression you entered has an invalid date value in access query

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a running balance of items in  a query.
the query has a date column ,item column and Bal column.
I want to get the sum balance after every day transaction.
I have tried the obvious Dsum function but get the message invalid date every time i run the query.
Dsum("[Bal]","Combined query","[Date]"<=#"& format([Date],"dd/mm/yyyy")&"#")
this is the query am using

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Dsum("[Bal]","Combined query","[Date] <= #" & Format([Date],"yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```